# ember-data dynamic number of DS.attr 's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ember.js, ember-data, mongomapper

So i have a ember-data model and i want my users to be able to create different / more DS.attr per item and call them whatever they like.    This will then send the json to rails server where i am using mondodb.   I can then check to see if key is defined and if not create it for this document and save it in mongo.

The problem is you have to hardcode all the DS.attr 's when extending the DS.Model but i dont know them all at that point.

Is there a way to reopen the DS.Model and somehow loop over the json keys passed ( or i could pass all keys in a allKeys field to the client from rails ???).

Then when someone wants to create a different attribute i can dynamically reopen the model and add this DS.attr ?

Anyone any ideas how to do this or if its even possible ??

Any help, examples or idea would me great!

thanks a lot
Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `App.Post` model and you want your users to store additional attributes for posts. First create a model `App.MyModelTypes` and store all your modelTypes in it:

```
App.MyModelTypes = DS.Model.extend({
  modelType: DS.attr('string') // e.g. App.Post, App.Comment
  attributes: DS.hasMany('App.Attribute')
});
```

Then your `App.Post` should like:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  // ... other base attributes
});
```

Define a model `App.Attribute` as follows:

```
App.Attribute = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
  attrType: DS.attr('string'),

  theModelType: DS.belongsTo('App.Model'),
  attributeValues: DS.hasMany('App.AttributeValue')
});
```

When a user creates a new attribute for post, the app should create a new `App.Attribute` that belongs to App.MyModelType `App.Post`.

Finally you need a model for storing the custom attributes values for Posts:

```
App.AttributeValue = DS.Model.extend({
  theModelType: DS.belongsTo('App.MyModelTypes'),
  targetId: DS.attr('number'),
  attribute: DS.belongsTo('App.Attribute'),
  value: DS.attr('string') // attribute.attrType will give us the type 
});
```

When a user edits the attribute value of a certain post, you store the `post.id` in `targetId`, in `theModelType` you store `App.Post`, etc.

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: hhhmmm !   thanks Zack but i dont really want to split my attributes away into different models as this will save them in different documents in different collection in mongodb.      This might be the way if i was using a relational db but i am not for this exact reason!     any other ideas ???    thanks a lot